# Is there way to increase speed of adding subtitles to a video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, subtitles

Currently I do it this way: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf ass=subs.ass output.mp4`.
But with some videos it takes too long.
Is there way to increase speed of that: may be saving output file with lesser quality or something?

Comment: The bottleneck is likely hardware related 1) slow write speed, are you writing out to an SSD? A 7200 RPM spinning disk? A network share? 2) slow CPU. Can you upgrade to a newer CPU? 3) RAM cap. Are you hitting a memory limit on the machine?

Comment: @spikey_richie HDD, no memory limit, it's not used much, can't upgrade CPU.

Comment: OK, so then yeah I guess your next step is to render the whole thing to a lower frame rate, or lower resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Use a faster `-preset`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset) (assuming you are using the encoder libx264).
- [Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio instead of re-encoding it with `-c:a copy` (assuming the input audio is AAC).
- Use softsubs instead of hardsubs (assuming your player accepts them) and avoid re-encoding entirely with stream copy. Either output to MKV and mux the ASS files, or use MP4 with `-c:s mov_text`.
- Experiment to see if a [hardware accelerated encoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) is faster.

Comment: Thanks for response, llogan. I tried this, no difference: `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf ass=SUBS.ass OUTPUT.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -c:a copy
`

Comment: @RSt Option placement matters. Your command has trailing options that are ignored. Use `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf ass=SUBS.ass -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4`

Comment: it does it, thank you very much! Do trailing arguments always (often) ignored in command line or it's in this program specifically?

Comment: @RSt It depends on the program.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this works for me and it is very Fast.

`ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -i "$subt_file" -c copy -c:s mov_text "$savefile"`

Also, if I need to delay subtitles I use this:

`ffmpeg -itsoffset 3.68 -i "/Plex/work/GC.srt" -c copy xx.srt`