# Is there way to increase speed of adding subtitles to a WEBM video?

Tags: ffmpeg, transcode, webm

With MP4 I used this command

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf ass=SUBS.ass -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 22 -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

[which has helped to increase the speed](https://superuser.com/questions/1577401/is-there-way-to-increase-speed-of-adding-subtitles-to-a-video).

But there are some problems with WebM format, I tried to use this command which didn't help

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf ass=SUBS.ass -c:v vp9 -crt 22 -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

Error occurs. Something like this:

> [webm @ 0x5] Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.

Do what they ask:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 18 -b:v 0 -c:a libopus -b:a 213k -ac 2 -c:s webvtt -y out.webm
```

replace options with yours.

[update]
For increasing speed better use MKV. Fastest way:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i subs.ass -map 0 -map 1 -c copy out.mkv
```

or MP4:

```
ffempg -i in.mp4 -i subs.ass -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:s mov_text out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks Баяр, at least it works now, but there is no increase in speed, so if anyone could add something...

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't increase speed, because you have to reencode every track in input files.

Comment: But I could reencode  in this case: https://superuser.com/questions/1577401/is-there-way-to-increase-speed-of-adding-subtitles-to-a-video Why can't I do something like that with WEBM?

Comment: You must reencode all tracks to another format to fit into WEBM. You can't copy some tracks for increasing speed. You can try to use hardware codec. If u have intel gpu use "-c:v vp9_qsv". Or do not use WEBM, use MP4 or MKV.

Comment: What to do if it says `Unknown encoder 'vp9_qsv'`?

Comment: "vp9_qsv" for windows only encoder